# why does this inline count() condition return an error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following t-sql works as expected:

```
--test1
DECLARE @IntValCount INT;
SELECT @IntValCount = COUNT(IntVal) FROM @AppIdList;
IF(@IntValCount = 0)
BEGIN
    print 'test1'
END
```

However, if I try to write the count() condition as an inline expression with the following sql then ssms returns the error "Incorrect syntax near '='":

```
--test2 
IF(SELECT COUNT(IntVal) FROM @AppIdList = 0)
BEGIN
    print 'test2'
END
```

Am I writing the sql for test2 incorrectly or dos ss not allow this particular approach for some reason?

Comment: the whole `SELECT` should be wrapped in parentheses: `IF((SELECT COUNT(IntVal) FROM @AppIdList) = 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Your parens are in the wrong place:

```
IF ( (SELECT COUNT(IntVal) FROM @AppIdList) = 0)
BEGIN
    print 'test2'
END;
```

However, it is better to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
IF ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @AppIdList WHERE IntVal IS NOT NULL) )
BEGIN
    print 'test2'
END;
```

Why?  `NOT EXISTS` can stop at the first matching value.  `SELECT COUNT()` has to read all the potential values.